# Printing out of bounds array contents

Tags: c++, arrays

Let's say I have an array:

```
string w[10];
```

and I have a statement:

```
if(w.size() > 10)
{
  // How would I print out the 11th character?
  char a = w[11];
  cout << a << endl;
}
```

How would I print out the 11th character? I tried storing into a character a but it didn't seem to print anything.

Comment: that doesn't make any sense....

Comment: [It really doesn't.](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/218/530/wtf_is_this_shit_Very_Disturbing_Childrens_Book_RE_We_dont_say_ampquotGermanampquot_in_America-s400x297-59009.jpg?1324142033)

Comment: Your main problem is that `string w[10]` is an array of 10 strings and **not** one string consisting of 10 chars.

Comment: Arrays don't have member functions. You cannot call `size()` on an array. Besides that, the question makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to print outside of the bounds of an array? Printing any character past the size of your array is undefined and might cause a crash.

Also w[11] is actually the 12th element. Since the array is 0 based the 11th element is w[10].

Do you actually want the array do be dynamically sized? Because if you are trying to use a string perhaps you want an stl string? That is defined in the header `<string>` and used via

```
std::string somestring("string you want");
```